# Add a line without quotes by means of PutAppend

Tags: export

I'd like to export string, for example, like this:

```
"ZT[1,1]={"blabla", 0, n+13, 4*g1*g2/3 + g2^2};"
```

to myfile.m and there i want to see:

```
ZT[1,1]={"blabla", 0, n+13, 4*g1*g2/3 + g2^2};
```

but no matter what I do, I get other results, for example, like this:

```
"ZT[1,1]={\"blabla\", 0, n+13 , 4*g1*g2/3 + \ g2^2}"
```

What I did:

```
PutAppend[StringJoin["ZT[",ToString[i],",",ToString[k],"]=" ,"{", ToString[Last[ReadList[StringJoin["!some command ","'",ToString[Z[i,k][[1]]],"'"],String]]] ,"}"], StringJoin["some_table_up_",ToString[somenumber],"_babam.m"]]
```

If I wrote `ToExpression`, I can get only:

```
{"blabla", 0, n+13 , 4*g1*g2/3 + g2^2}
```

but I need a variable before it.

Thank you so much!

Comment: What's wrong with `WriteString`? That is exactly what you want to do, I think.

Comment: Nothing =), just among the abundance of mathematica commands, I did not reach it) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Unevaluated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unevaluated):

```
Put["first line", "tmp.m"]
PutAppend[
    Unevaluated[ZT[1,1]={"blabla",0,n+13,4*g1*g2/3+g2^2};],
    "tmp.m"
]
Import["tmp.m","String"]
```

> "first line"
>
> ZT[1, 1] = {"blabla", 0, n + 13, 4*g1*(g2/3) + g2^2};

If you must use a string instead of an expression, then you can do:

```
With[
    {
    str=ToExpression[
        "ZT[1,1]={\"blabla\", 0, n+13 , 4*g1*g2/3 + \ g2^2}",
        StandardForm,
        Unevaluated
    ]
    },

    Put[1,"tmp.m"];
    PutAppend[str, "tmp.m"]
]

Import["tmp.m", "String"]
```

> 1
>
> ZT[1, 1] = {"blabla", 0, n + 13, 4*g1*(g2/3) + g2^2}

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It helped me as well as option of solution suggested by b3m2a1!